# How do I diagnose proxying problems of install4j?

Tags: proxy, install4j

This is about install4j itself, not the installers it can generate.

If something is wrong with the proxy settings, e.g. in "Download JREs" is just get a generic "something went wrong" message, or the download hangs indefinitely: How do I find out what actually went wrong?

Relevant diagnostic information includes:

- Did it take the proxy configuration from the wrong place (autodetected Internet Settings vs. registry)
- What were the actual settings used? I.e. concrete technical parameters: DNS name, IP address, port, authentication type, password/NTLM token used.
- What DNS domain / IP address did it try to access? This is important because sometimes, firewalls and proxies tend to interact in complicated ways, so you need to know the concrete server to go to the Internet Connectivity Department and tell them which domain/server has become unreachable after the latest firewall update. (Partial answer: "Check for Updates" actually provides this in case of an error. This information would be good to have even in case of when it works, for situations where on machine works and the other does not. JRE list retrieval in "Download JREs" does not give that information in the error case, anyway.)
- What was the actual problem - no connection, certificate mismatch? (A certificate mismatch happens if an HTTPS connection is intercepted by a proxy, which could be a corporate proxy (okay) or a malicious attacker (not okay).)

Some of the installer advice transfers to install4j itself, but sometimes -D parameter names are different, and some parameters do not seem to exist at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bin/install4j.vmoptions`, add

```
-Dinstall4j.showConnectError=true
```

then you will see some debug info in `%TEMP%\install4j_error.log`, in particular the used proxy settings will be printed as well as the response code and response headers if the connection fails.

Comment: (Thanks for the quick response btw)

Comment: No, this particular option is not documented.

Comment: Pity. Sites like stackexchange help, but the info can be incomplete, outdated, or inaccurate, so docs from the source are always preferred. But your feedback does help. A lot :-)